# How to deploy Vista SP2 with a Vista SP1 media?

Tags: mdt-2010, windows, service-pack

**Description of the problem:**
When I try to create an image with Vista SP2 for deployment from a Vista SP1 installation media I'm encountering some installation errors which I can't solve after a lot of research. When I asked for support on the MDT blog I got recommended to use the Vista SP2 media but that media seems to not exist at the moment...

As far as I know there are no proper ways to slipstream it into the installation media as there will be a version mismatch resulting in installation errors. Besides that I'm not going to download anything integrated as that is just a risk as I need to deploy towards customers.

Above problem is holding me back in deploying, as not being able to have SP2 done during installation causes me to have to do the whole updating process with interaction after the automated LTI.

**My questions:**
Does anyone have a suggestion on how I could deploy Vista SP2 when I currently have the Vista SP1 media? Does someone know when the Vista SP2 installation media becomes available?

I'm using Microsoft Deployment Toolkit 2010, I have tried capturing a SP2 installation without succes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WAIK to integrate your language pack into Vista SP2 English media and set it as default language. You can easily find language packs around or download them from VL, MSDN etc. I'm pretty sure you can find them from Microsoft Update catalog, but i didn't bother to check myself.
I have repeadedly used this method to create custom images (3 languages etc).

It should be easy after that.

Comment: "MUIs require a license to be used and are only available with Windows Vista Ultimate and Windows Vista Enterprise.", but we install Windows Vista Home Premium most of the time. So this isn't an option either, thank you for trying...

Comment: You're not using MUIs with Home Premium. The idea of MUI is being able to change languages on the fly. With HP you can only select it at install, so you're not using MUIs, simply different languages. If i remember correctly, licence keys aren't related to languages, so legally you should be safe, because simply modifiying images does not violate EULA.

Comment: Ah, together with the documentation on it I understand it now. You can insert full language packs in the image though you can only select one on the first boot. Will try this too. :-)

Comment: Any luck with that? I'd like some reputation, if my solution worked. =)

Comment: Whoa, that worked just fine! Thanks alot, also thanks to Massimo, I wish I could accept multiple answers... :-P

Answer (score 1):

Vista SP2 media ***is*** available... on MSDN, at least.

Anyway, have you tried installing SP2 on a vista SP1 computer and capturing an image of it using the "Sysprep and capture" MDT task sequence?

Comment: Too be more specific, in Belgium the media "Vista SP2 Dutch" is not available yet, thus we are not able to obtain it in any way. Yes, I have tried that, and it results in errors after reinstallation because the installer of the Vista SP1 media doesn't have the purpose to do an installation of Vista SP2. Any update that makes the kernel version change renders the deployment of the captured image useless, and you will get a return code 13 when trying, tried all solutions I could find on that return code so that's not the way to go.

Comment: You should use the latest Windows PE to run the task sequence. Which Windows Automated Installation (WAIK) did you install on the deployment server?

Comment: As the Deployment Toolkit got just released I am using the latest version for that, the same counts for Windows AIK. It's the newest version with support for Windows 7, I can't find a version number but it lists "Build Date: 2009-04-23-230528" in the documentary of Windows AIK. Besides that I just noticed that Vista SP2 is not listed on http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=696DD665-9F76-4177-A811-39C26D3B3B34&displaylang=en So I'm still stuck... :-(

Comment: You can try this: get the install media for Windows Vista SP2 **English** and import that in MDT; use this OS image to create the sysprep&capture task sequence; build your reference computer using Windows Vista **Dutch** and apply SP2; capture it using the task sequence you created in MDT. Even if language is different, the OS release is the same, so the capture *should* work.

Comment: Placing the wim with the SP2 sources might be an idea, but I wonder if it will be language compatible. Well, it's an idea to try, in the worst case I have to wait or hope for some other solution to show up somewhere...

Comment: I deployed succesfully in mixed-language environments like the one I suggested, so I'm quite sure it *should* work. Try it.

Comment: Sure, will do it when I have some free time later this day. Opened up a bounty to hear from other people that have had the same experience and have another solution for this problem. If not, the 100 reputation bounty is yours... ;-)